# MYSQL Select statement explanation

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have the following MYSQL select statement in a php file that was provided me by a programmer sometime ago.

I'm trying to make some edits to the file (I know enough PHP to "get myself into trouble").

Unfortunately, I don't understand this statement and what it means.  I've never seen a select statement with "DOTS" in it (ie. a.weight or b.oil_type_id)

I don't understand howto read it.  Here's the statement.  Anyone know what this is supposed to mean?

```
$query11 = "SELECT avg(a.weight) as weight_avg
           from oil_type a, oil_data b
           where b.oil_type_id = a.oiltype_id
           and b.viscosity_id = ". $viscosity_id_this;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are *qualifying* the columns with their table names (or rather, their aliases):

```sql
SELECT avg( a.weight ) as weight_avg 
  FROM oil_type a, oil_data b  -- b is an alias for oil_data, a is an alias for oil_type
                               -- also, there's an implicit join here
 WHERE b.oil_type_id = a.oiltype_id 
   AND b.viscosity_id =". $viscosity_id_this;
```

This is necessary to remove ambiguity (ie: when a column with the same name exists in both tables). If the column names are not the same, you could use this for clarity.

The whole query could be rewritten as:

```sql
    SELECT AVG(a.weight) as weight_avg 
      FROM oil_type AS a
INNER JOIN oil_data AS b 
        ON b.oil_type_id = a.oiltype_id 
     WHERE b.viscosity_id = $viscosity_id_this;
```

Which might be more clear (or not).

Comment: With commented notation directly in the coding, and the more verbose version of the query, this proved to be the response that clarified things best for me.  Thank you.

Comment: Could I ask a quick follow-up?  What is being averaged, then -"AVG(a.weight)"?  Does this mean that the average of the weight column from the oil_type table is being calculated?  If so, I'm having trouble making sense of that because this column has only 3 values in it and the average of those values wouldn't really be useful.  Confused.

Comment: Never mind, think I think I understand.  The "weight" column is now the "weight" column of the joined table, which is basically a new column that applies to all records of the "oil_data" table.  If that makes sense.  It is a "generated" column, based on the criteria of the select query, right?

Comment: @Michael It's the average of the `weight` column from the `oil_type` table. But this will only take the average of the rows selected. You can see what these rows are if you change `AVG(a.weight)` to just `a.weight`

Answer (score 4):

It's the table alias. Notice in your query :

```
-- ...
FROM oil_type a
```

oil_type can now be referred to with the alias a. Therefore, when you see `a.weight`, it actually means `oil_type.weight`.

This is necessary in this case because there is a `weight` column in both tables you are selecting from. If you used only `weight`, MySQL wouldn't know which `weight` column to use, and would therefore return an error.

*Edit*: As Phil pointed in comments, there isn't necessarily two `weight` columns in this case, for some odd reason I thought you were joining your table with itself (therefore obviously duplicating the columns).

Comment: Nothing indicates a duplicate column name in the joined table though in such a case, qualifying the column name would indeed be necessary.

Comment: Phil: You're right, actually for some reason I thought he was joining the table with itself.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance.  I tried to mark your post as helpful, even though not the answer that was MOST helpful to me, but, since I'm new, the system wouldn't let me.  Anyway.  Thank you.  The combination of all of the answers here painted a very clear picture for me and will really help clarify some things.

Answer (score 2):

And even more - you can refer to it as `database_name.table_name.column_name` and have 2 dots in one name

Comment: I don't mean to be a dick, but how is this an answer?

Comment: It is FQN for column, and imho it explains author his confusion (I've never seen a select statement with "DOTS" in it (ie. a.weight or b.oil_type_id))

Comment: This was a helpful addition, even if NullUser... didn't think so.  I thought his explanation was most directly useful to my question, but, this addition I don't think was provided by anyone else and is related to the question I asked (even if only indirectly).  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When selecting from multiple tables, the table name or its alias may be used, followed by a `.` and the column name in order to reduce/remove ambiguity between similarly named columns.

In this case, table `oil_type` is aliased as `a` and `oil_data` is aliased as `b`.